# Multibit application on Mac only showing 2/7 wallets

Tags: wallet, multibit

I've got 7 wallets created in Multibit. Since today, when i open Multibit it is only showing 2 wallets out of the 7 that exist.

I've checked the files stored in user/Library/Application Support/Multibit and all the .wallet are still there.

I don't know how to solve this issue...

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after trying different things and updating multibit software i managed to recover my missing wallet by creating new wallet with the exact name of the .wallet that existed in the Multibit Application. If i had a garbage.wallet and was not showing in Multibit, i created manually a new garbage.wallet and that recovered my old multibit wallet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'File | Open' command, navigate to where the 'something'.wallet file is, select it and then click 'Open'.

It will then reopen the wallet and synchronize it.